App crashes in flutter stripe payment sheet when clicking on erase pink icon (android device)
App crashes immediatly when clicking on the pink erase icon

There is already an issue on github https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/issues/1560
Strack Trace :
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596): Process: com.inspark.annuaire_entreprise, PID: 1596
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getEmojiStart(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;I)I in class Landroidx/emoji2/text/EmojiCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.emoji2.text.EmojiCompat' appears in /data/app/~~10DiFKQl9tb4z5ybPgq0-g==/com.inspark.annuaire_entreprise-1moyKcUoju89JThTUqhVxg==/base.apk!classes19.dex)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at androidx.compose.foundation.text.StringHelpers_androidKt.findPrecedingBreak(StringHelpers.android.kt:24)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at androidx.compose.foundation.text.selection.BaseTextPreparedSelection.getPrecedingCharacterIndex(TextPreparedSelection.kt:150)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at androidx.compose.foundation.text.TextFieldKeyInput$process$2$3.invoke(TextFieldKeyInput.kt:131)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at androidx.compose.foundation.text.TextFieldKeyInput$process$2$3.invoke(TextFieldKeyInput.kt:129)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at androidx.compose.foundation.text.selection.TextFieldPreparedSelection.deleteIfSelectedOr(TextPreparedSelection.kt:397)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at androidx.compose.foundation.text.TextFieldKeyInput$process$2.invoke(TextFieldKeyInput.kt:129)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at androidx.compose.foundation.text.TextFieldKeyInput$process$2.invoke(TextFieldKeyInput.kt:106)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at androidx.compose.foundation.text.TextFieldKeyInput.commandExecutionContext(TextFieldKeyInput.kt:226)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at androidx.compose.foundation.text.TextFieldKeyInput.process-ZmokQxo(TextFieldKeyInput.kt:106)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at androidx.compose.foundation.text.TextFieldKeyInputKt$textFieldKeyInput$2$1.invoke-ZmokQxo(TextFieldKeyInput.kt:261)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at androidx.compose.foundation.text.TextFieldKeyInputKt$textFieldKeyInput$2$1.invoke(TextFieldKeyInput.kt:261)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at androidx.compose.ui.input.key.KeyInputNode.onKeyEvent-ZmokQxo(KeyInputModifier.kt:80)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at androidx.compose.ui.focus.FocusOwnerImpl.dispatchKeyEvent-ZmokQxo(FocusOwnerImpl.kt:193)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.dispatchKeyEvent(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:647)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1993)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1993)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1993)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1993)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1993)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1993)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:561)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1901)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:4219)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.superDispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:126)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at androidx.core.view.KeyEventDispatcher.dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEventDispatcher.java:86)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:144)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:604)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:3413)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:448)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6592)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:6449)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5922)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5984)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5945)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6119)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5953)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:6176)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5926)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5984)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5945)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5953)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5926)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8942)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:8893)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8854)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessageImpl(ViewRootImpl.java:5682)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:5554)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:233)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:344)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8191)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:584)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1596):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1034)
I/Process ( 1596): Sending signal. PID: 1596 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.
and they said it's fixed in version 10.0.0 ( I'm using version 9.6.0)
I tried using version 10.0.0 following this documentation App build failed pointing on that stripe dependency
Is there any solution to fix this issue ?

Updating flutter version which is the last thing i wanted to do fixed the issue
